# how to use form:select of spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm having the following two classes which has one to many mapping. A student can select multiple subjects.

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "studentinfo" )
public class student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column ( name = "stud_id" )
    private int studId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column ( name = "stud_name" )
    private String studname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column ( name = "stud_age" )
    private int studage;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn ( name = "stud_sub_id" )
    private List<subject> subject;

    //getters and setters
```

subject model class

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "subject" )
public class subject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column ( name = "Sub_id" )
private int subId;

@NotEmpty
@Column ( name = "Subj_name" )
private String subjname;

//getters and setters
```

How can i use form:select tag to display the list of subjects so that, i can select multiple subject for a student and also while editing a particular student detail, i need to display the selected subjects for him. Here is my current jsp code.

```
<form:form commandName="studentdetails" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stud/studentadded" method="post">
     <form:hidden path="studId"/>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="studname">Name: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="studname" id="name"/></td>
             <td><form:errors path="studname" cssStyle="color:#ff0000"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="studage">Age: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="studage" id="age"/></td>
             <td><form:errors path="studage" cssStyle="color:#ff0000"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="subject.subjname">Opting Subject: </label> </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="subject.subjname"> 
                <form:option value="" label="select"></form:option>     
                <form:options items="${subjects}"/>         
                </form:select>
            </td>
             <td><form:errors path="subject.subjname" cssStyle="color:#ff0000"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
            <td colspan="3">

                <input type="Submit" value="Add"/>

            </td>
        </tr>

     </table>
      </form:form>
```

My form backing object is of student class. Here items = "${subjects}" contains the list of subjects in `List<String>` that i pass from the controller. For path = "subject.subjname" it is displaying the following error;

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'subject.subjname' of bean class [com.model.studentinfo]: Bean property 'subject.subjname' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

But i'm having the proper getters & setters. If i use path = "subject", i'm getting the following error while submitting.

```
400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
```

But i'm not using any date property. How can i make the form:select working for both adding and editing student. Please help me with this.

Comment: Try studendetails.subject.subjname in your path.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working.

Comment: Any one kindly help me with this.

Comment: Mate can you please wait for a bit will post code for u. Away from my computer

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks.

Comment: Any one knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Set of String inputSubjects field in your form backing object "studentdetails" and in the path use the following:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="studentdetails" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stud/studentadded" method="post">

    <form:select multiple="true" path="inputSubjects"> 
            <form:option value="" label="select"></form:option>     
            <form:options items="${subjects}"/>         
    </form:select>
```